# Get a raw mongo db reference in MeteorJS

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am writing a migration. The definition of a schema is deleted because of a purpose. I need to get access to the collection to run the next migration.
It does not satisfy.

```
let cb = new Mongo.Collection('CallingBundles')
```

It has to look like.

```js
db.collection('CallingBundles')
```

So. I can not get a reference to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Meteor uses a wrapper around the native Mongo driver. Use `rawDatabase` to access the db.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawDatabase

Answer (score 2):

The variant when a schema available.

```js
someCollection.rawDatabase();
```

More common solution

```js
MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db
```